# ZIO Json: Failing Fiber on List in Json

Tags: json, scala, zio, zio-json

I've got some data structures which I'm trying to hydrate from JSON. The short version (or [the full version here](https://gist.github.com/Aarkon/4b756e3032d86773b1bc24434f430bdc)):

```scala
sealed trait CexPair:
    val timestamp: String
    // ... (cut for brevity)
  implicit val decoderCexPair: JsonDecoder[CexPair] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen

case class CexPairWithBidAsk(
      timestamp: String,
      // snip
      bid: Double,
      ask: Double
  ) extends CexPair
  implicit val decoderWithBidAsk: JsonDecoder[CexPairWithBidAsk] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen

case class CexPairWithoutBidAsk(
    timestamp: String,
    // snip
  ) extends CexPair
  implicit val decoderWithoutBidAsk: JsonDecoder[CexPairWithoutBidAsk] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen

case class Tickers(data: Seq[CexPair])
implicit val decoderTickers: JsonDecoder[Tickers] = DeriveJsonDecoder.gen

implicit val decoderPairs: JsonDecoder[Seq[CexPair]] =
  decoderTickers.map(_.data)
```

But when I try to run this, I get:

```
Assertion failed:
  Fiber failed.
  A checked error was not handled.
  .data(expected '{' got '[')
```

This tells me that deserializing `Tickers` already goes haywire. Is this because a `sealed trait` is not the ideal basis for unmarshalling JSON or am I missing something entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

For you test case that is trying to parse `tickers <- ZIO.fromEither(str.fromJson[Tickers])`, he custom `JsonDecoder` `decodePairs` expects the `data` field of `Tickers` to also be parsed  as `Tickers` (before mapping in a `Seq`) instead of a `List` \ `Seq` hence it is expecting `{` instead of `[`.

Just remove `decoderPairs` and it will fallback to the default decoder for `Seq` and hopefully it should parse fine if there are no other issues.

Comment: That gives me another error: `Fiber failed.
  A checked error was not handled.
  .data[0](invalid disambiguator)`

Comment: We need to see the data you are parsing, can you provide a small sample that reproduces the errors?

Comment: Of course, I could have thought about that myself: https://cex.io/rest-api#ticker

Comment: You cannot use a `sealed trait` (ADT) for data like this, the paser would not be able to disambiguate between `CexPairWithBidAsk` and `CexPairWithoutBidAsk`. See in the fruit example how it needs the "Banana" and "Apple" keys: https://zio.github.io/zio-json/docs/overview/overview_decoding. I would suggest you use a single case class to represent `CexPair` and for the fields that might be missing use a `Maybe` type.

Comment: I mean `Option` type. `Maybe` is for Haskell.

Comment: I didn't ask if you needed but if you wanted them, trying to be polite. I don't see how I gave you the impression that I'm lazy here though. Never mind, thank you anyway.

Comment: "I didn't ask if you needed but if you wanted them". So which of your existing comments did you "ask if I wanted them"? Noone is obligated to tell you how they voted. You can make a report if you think the votes aren't fair.